# Writing an operating system for arm architecture

Tags: operating-system, arm

How do I get started writing an operating system that runs on the arm architecture?  I want to write a bootloader if possible and my own kernel.  Can anyone help me get started?

Comment: You should get started in *some* way, and then post on this site if you have specific, answerable questions related to programming. Good luck with your OS!

Comment: See also [How can I get started on writing my own mobile OS for ARM processors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954184/how-can-i-get-started-on-writing-my-own-mobile-os-for-arm-processors)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd start by familiarising yourself with what is already out there - Linux is a good start. Look at the bootloaders used in the distributions on the rPi - what is used in Debian Squeeze for example, [uBoot](http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot) and [BareBox](http://barebox.org/). Another option is CFE - which is under BSD license and good during debugging/early development.

Another thing is to look at the ucLinux and ucLibC systems, along with buildroot and OpenWRT - all designed to squeeze it onto a small system.

Of course - building your own kernel - you are going to want to go far deeper - and spend time understanding MMU's, process management/multitasking, interrupts and so on. A good background in programming microcontrollers, a knowledge of assembler language and CPU/SOC architecture would be essential. With the ARM family - you'll want to know the various instruction sets supported, and which chips have features like MMU's, FPU's and similar.

Good luck - it sounds like an interesting project.

Comment: Grub is probably a really bad place to start as it's an x86 boot-loader, built around the brain-dead and now very obsolete (yet still used) PC architecture pre-boot environment and BIOS. Large parts of it are irrelevant to ARM SoC systems. 

[uBoot](http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot) and [Barebox](http://barebox.org) are ARM bootloaders - the latter being rather more hackable. 

Incidentally, no micro-code on any ARM device.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Marco. I'll edit the corrections into the answer - I know of Grub and Lilo, and a number of in house bootloaders that I'm not going to disclose. At least the starting point has lead to some discussions.

Comment: If they were building on x86, GRUB and the Multiboot standard are the way to go, but for ARM, uBoot and Barebox are good suggestions.